# Plotting ODE as it is being solved in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

So, I'm solving some ODEs in MATLAB using ode45. Nothing particularly complicated about them or the code, but each ODE solution takes 20-30 minutes to obtain, and I need to get about 10. (It's a parameter sweep.)

While sitting and waiting for the solutions to arrive, I find myself wishing there was some way to watch the solutions be plotted out as the ODEs are solved, both to reassure myself that progress is being made and to be able to end the solver if something seems to be off about the solution.

Is there a way to return the current (incomplete) solution from ode45 and plot it in real time as it's being solved? I'm currently plotting the solutions as they arrive, but that still takes some time, and real time would be fantastic.

Comment: The correct answer is to use an [`OutputFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#input_argument_namevalue_OutputFcn) – see the [`ballode`](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex84325677-simple-event-location-a-bouncing-ball) example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you were to plot it in real time, you'd have to edit the code of the solver itself. In doing so, I imagine it would cause the solver to slow to a crawl when you run it because it has to graphically plot what it's doing. Not much of an answer im afraid, but for some reason the site didnt let me post this as a comment...

Comment: That's what I had feared, although I hadn't though of the time delay in plotting - d'oh. Thanks!

Comment: But its always worth a shot. Have a close look at the ode45 code and see if you can siphon out some realtime data by editing the code

Comment: Yes, this is not really an answer and it is wrong – you don't need to edit the solver itself. Just use an `OutputFcn`.

Comment: @horchler could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did to ode45 to make it plot while running

%line 470

f(:,1) = f(:,7);  % Already have f(tnew,ynew)

%make plot

plot(tout(1:nout),yout(:,1:nout))

drawnow

%end of addition

end

....

Comment: This is a bad way to do this. `ode45` is an adaptive solver, so your integration function is called multiple times per integration step and some pf the calls will result in failed steps.